# JSP parallel include

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

One thing I like about JSP is include mechanism. In JSP I can simply write:

```
<jsp:include page='/widget/foo-widget?param=value' />
```

It works very well when I have some sort of widget and I want incude it on some other page.

The other day I think, It would be nice if include doesn't block thread control, so if I have several includes, they could be processed in parallel. Is there any way to do it in JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't and it is also not worth the effort. HTML response is to be streamed sequentially anyway.

If you're *actually* doing expensive business stuff to preprocess one and other, then you should already not be using JSP for that, but a Servlet where you've the freedom to spawn threads. This still ought to be done carefully, you don't want to leak threads or to have deadlocks. The [`java.util.concurrent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) API may be helpful in this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `<jsp:param>` standard action when putting parameters in a `<jsp:include>`.  This is good because it properly encodes the parameter for inclusion in a URL.

```
<jsp:include page="/widget/foo-widget">
  <jsp:param name="param" value="value" />
</jsp:include>
```

Comment: not an answer to the question, but useful. Thanks, I upvote.